# Html / Php form not adding to SQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I've been working on this for hours now and including rebuilding my whole code I cannot figure out what is wrong. The HTML form is supposed to populate the patients SQL database but it is not working. I have a similar form that I am using on another part of the website that works flawlessly but this on doesn't seem to and a can't figure out why.

thanks for your help

Here is a picture of thedatabase fields :
[Database fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhiFj.png)

Heres the code:

```html
<?php

//session_start();

//if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
//  header("Location: /");
//}

require 'connection.php';

$message = '';

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['dob']) && !empty($_POST['nok']) && !empty($_POST['nok_add']) && !empty($_POST['nok_phone'])&& !empty($_POST['doa'])&& !empty($_POST['allergies'])):
  
  // Enter the new user in the database
  $sql = "INSERT INTO patients (name, dob, nok, nok_add, nok_phone, doa, allergies) VALUES (:name, :dob, :nok, :nok_add, :nok_phone, :doa, :allergies)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':dob', $_POST['dob']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nok', $_POST['nok']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nok_add', $_POST['nok_add']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nok_phone', $_POST['nok_phone']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':doa', $_POST['doa']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':allergies', $_POST['allergies']);

  if( $stmt->execute() ):
    $message = 'Successfully created new user';
  else:
    $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
  endif;

endif;



?>


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Patient Add</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
      <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?fami=Roboto:400,300,200,100&subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">      
        #headline {
        padding: 0.8em;
        color: white;
        font-family: Roboto, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: black;
        background-image: url(backgroundimage.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
      } 

</style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="headline">
      <div class="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Patient Add</h1>
          <p></p>
        </header>



    <button onClick="window.location='manager_select.php';" class="_button">Back</button>
    <form method="POST" id="add">
          
      <h2>Enter the Patient's Details</h2>

      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name">

      <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
      <input type="text" name="dob">

      <label for="nok">Next of Kin:</label>
      <input type="text" name="nok">

      <label for="nok_add">Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="nok_add">

      <label for="nok_phone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="text" name="nok_phone">

      <label for="doa">Date of Admission:</label>
      <input type="text" name="dob">

      <label for="allergies">Allergies:</label>
      <input type="text" name="allergies">

      <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
        <p><?= $message ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <input type="submit">

    </form>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

  <!-- // [START footer] -->
      <footer>
        <div class="container">
          <p>Copyright Ghyll Court Residental Home 2017</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- // [END footer] -->

  </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
          window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)").addListener(hitMQ);
        }

        function hitMQ(evt) {
          sampleCompleted("GettingStarted-ContentWithStyles");
        }

        init();

      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are your $_POST even coming through? print_r($_POST); above your if test

Comment: Enable the error by adding error_reporting(E_ALL); in the top of the page.

Comment: Is it printing one of the `$message` values?

Comment: @Barmar no its not printing any of the $message values.

Comment: Then the `if()` statement at the beginning must not be succeeding. Check the values in `$_POST`.

Comment: @clearshot66 yes thanks for the tip. I have just done that and they are coming through. This is what came up    
?> Array ( [name] => [dob] => [nok] => [nok_add] => [nok_phone] => [allergies] => )

Comment: the commented out sessions code is questionable. You are using pdo to connnect with, right?

Comment: That mean's the data is empty....like it should look like [name]=>Jeff[dob]=>03-30-2017

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Yes I am using PDO in my connection file!

Comment: @clearshot66 sorry forgot to input the data yes that is what happens.

Comment: any ideas then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered on your [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128797/html-php-not-updating-sql-database) (also answering here for completeness), you're checking for a "doa" field in your `if` statement, which doesn't exist. Your form defines "dob" twice: once for Date of Birth, and once for Date of Admission:

```
<label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
<input type="text" name="dob">

...

<label for="doa">Date of Admission:</label>
<input type="text" name="dob">
```

Comment: this is the right answer as far as i can see, as he said you have no field for "doa" so it will always be "empty" and your if() statement will never execute.

Comment: @rickdenhann thankyou so much for you help its the little things that you don't see!

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about this being the safest way but instead of using MSQLI PDO why don't you try simple `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`